# Trigger a button when enter button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with this code here:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sX6X/70/)

What I am trying to do is trigger the "Add" button of the specific line when the input field in this line is focused and the enter button is hit.

As far as I can guess it's something a bit like this:

```
$("#current").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#add").submit();
    }
});
```

I've tried to get a few different things working but this is almost the first code I have written in Javascript and I'm getting a little bit stuck. Could anyone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: should work, what happens when you click?

Comment: The first thing I would say is that you have multiple `#current` events. This is invalid and won't work as you expect. `id` attributes must be unique.

Comment: It might help having an element with ID of `add` :)

Comment: If it's just enter ... can't u try to set focus on it?
`$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").focus();
})`

Comment: try `$("#add").trigger("click");`

Comment: sry ... just checked the code ... you need enter to be same as add when he is typing in a box? Like box1 on enter add1 , box2 on enter add2 ... ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fM4NE/ - this works

Comment: And just the others said ... current should be a class. You can't have more items with same id

Comment: No, I just want enter in the current field to "add"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from your `current` ID's not being unique, you can do the following:

```
$(".current").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(this).next("input.add").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9sX6X/77/

(I changed your repeating ID's to classes for `current`)

Answer (score 1):

you have no element which id = "add" 
maybe you want the button chick

you can use

$('this').next('.add').trigger('click');

Answer (score 1):

Well, first **you shoudn't have the same id for several elements**.

Then, the code you posted is what you are looking for, replace

```
$("#add").submit();
```

by

```
$(this).next().click();
```

(but there are other ways to get the button)

```
    //bind a function to the "keyup" event for the element of id "current"
    $("#current").keyup(function(e) {
            // if the key pressed is 13 (code for enter)
            if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                //trigger the click event on the next element (in this cas your button)
                $(this).next().click();
            }
        });
```

`

Answer (score 0):

just follow this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9sX6X/81/

### Details

```
<form name="input" class="form">
    <fieldset>
        <h4>Requirements</h4>
        <div class="copies"></div>
        <div class="line">
            <input id="current" type="text" name="content" placeholder="Requirement" />
            <input type="button" value="Add" class="add" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h4>Qualifications</h4>
        <div class="copies"></div>
        <div class="line">
            <input id="current" type="text" name="content" placeholder="Qualification" />
            <input type="button" value="Add" class="add" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h4>Benefits</h4>
        <div class="copies"></div>
        <div class="line">
            <input id="current" type="text" name="content" placeholder="Benefit" />
            <input type="button" value="Add" class="add" />
        </div>
    <fieldset>
</form>

<script>
//latest
var maxFields = 10;

function cloneLine(line){
    var nb = 1 + $(line).siblings(".line").length;
    if (nb < 10){
        $(line).clone().insertAfter(line).find("[type=text]").val("").focus();
    }
    else{
        alert("Maximum fields number reached ! ");   
    }
}

<script>
// Listen to "add" clicks
$(document).on("click", ".add", function(e){
    // Try to clone the line 
    cloneLine($(this).parent());
})
// Listen to [enter] in <input type="text>
.on("keypress", "input[type=text]", function(e){
    // Not [enter] pressed ? Do nothing
    if (e.keyCode != 13){
        return;
    }
    // From here, [enter] was pressed

    // Prevent form submission
    e.preventDefault();    

    // Try to clone the line 
    cloneLine($(this).parent());   
});
</script>
```